# git push verbose, Entity Too Large, due to .git/objects/pack/

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am unable to git push to remote due to excessive data size. My largest directory is 331MB (total 525MB) but my .git directory is 40GB, mostly due to .git/objects/pack/

The verbose output (git push -v) is not very verbose (see below), so I don't know anything more than that.

**Q1.** Is there a more verbose setting for git push that will help me see what object it fails on specifically?

**Q2.** Is my .git/objects/pack abnormally large for my total code/file size? If so, how can I reduce it?

```
> git pull
> git push -v

Counting objects: 40, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (38/38), done.
error: RPC failed; HTTP 413 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 413 Request Entity Too Large
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (40/40), 23.49 GiB | 219.65 MiB/s, done.
Total 40 (delta 23), reused 2 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

NB. I am using git 2.7.4 with bitbucket on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: 40GB sounds fairly large.  Do you have any large binary files, such as images or library files, in your repo?

Comment: Bitbucket won't accept your repository, it has a soft limit of 1GB (it will start complaining about the size) and a hard limit of 2GB, you can't push a repository bigger than that to it. Why is the repository this big?

Comment: There are a handful of small audio files (total 22MB), but nothing close to 1GB.

Comment: Well, *something* takes up space in your repository, try executing `git fsck` and make sure it isn't corrupt. Then execute `git count-objects -v` and report the output in your question.

Comment: Thank you @LasseV.Karlsen, apparently I have many GBs of garbage.

warning: garbage found: .git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_doWnHh  ... 
warning: garbage found: .git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_Ipxc3j  ... 
warning: garbage found: .git/objects/ca/tmp_obj_glq395  ... 
count: 1611  ... 
size: 719316  ... 
in-pack: 431  ... 
packs: 6  ... 
size-pack: 24782836  ... 
prune-packable: 18  ... 
garbage: 3  ... 
size-garbage: 16435590  ... 

`git fsck` reveals quite a few dangling blobs and dangling commits.

Comment: After running garbage collection (`git gc --aggressive --prune`) and repacking (`git repack -Ad`), I still have a 25GB pack file :/ (pretty nice improvement over 40GB, but still too big...) Is there any other option besides simply deleting my local repo and cloning the origin again?

Comment: Solved now (see accepted answer below). There were indeed some very large files committed in previous history, which lingered in the pack but were no longer in my work tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1** - There's not a lot to say here; your repo is too large for bitbucket.

**Q2** - The pack file contains the database - i.e. the diffed/compressed history of your project.  This can vary in size wildly relative to your work tree, for a lot of reasons.  (For example, how much history is there?  What kinds of files?)  That said, both your work tree and your database seem large, which makes me think you're storing large binary files.  (Images.  Compiled program code - .jar, .war, .lib, .exe, ...)

By itself, git isn't very good at handling large binaries.  If you're pulling in .jar or other dependency library type files, consider using build tools to fetch them instead of storing them in source control.  If you're storing binary assets that really need to be part of your source tree, consider using git lfs.

You can use a tool like the BFG Repo Cleaner or lfs-migrate to rewrite your repo so that it uses lfs.  I've used both - sometimes together, though there are tricks to making them play nice.  Each has its pros and cons.

And/Or, you can ditch some or all of the history to conserve space.  Even starting with a fresh repo, if you have large binary assets, use lfs or find a way not to store them in git, or you'll just run into the same problem again soon.

Comment: Thank you, Mark! BFG Repo Cleaner worked. It removed two very large files I had mistakenly commited previously but which were no longer in my working directory. They remained in the history, recorded in the pack file.